# Receptive field in input image size estimation for object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Faster RCNN in tensorflow with *Resnet 101*. Using some information gathered from  trying to find the best parameters for [blogs](https://github.com/jaspereb/FasterRCNNTutorial) or [discussions](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/112) I understood that for better accuracy I should consider the input size of my images, the relative size of my bboxes and also the receptive field of my model.

Correct me if I am mistaking but the latter is defined in each model's architecture. So, in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/receptive_field) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/receptive_field/RECEPTIVE_FIELD_TABLE.md) I found that *Resnet 101* has a receptive field of 1027. Does this mean that image sizes should be close to this to be fully exploited? This seems remarkably close to the predefined `max_dimension: 1024` in the config sample files in [git](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs). The only one being different is [faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config#L18) because images are too "stretched". In this case they don't seem to bother for being quite bigger than 1027.

My dataset contains image of varying sizes as well bboxes of varying sizes. My strategy is to try to create similar sized bboxes in every case:

1. Images with small bbox will be cropped to create more tiled/patched images from a single one (with the disadvantage of some bboxes being split) in order for the final bboxes in input images to be above a size (e.g. 30x30)
2. Images with bigger bboxes will be padded to create smaller bboxes.

So, should I take into consideration the receptive field of my model?